# Getting error while converting JPG to PDF via ghostscript using TCL script

Tags: tcl, exec, ghostscript

I tried to execute the command with open command also

```
set command "C:\Program Files(x86)\gs\bin\gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o $createpdfpath D:/test/1/ghostscript/gs9.19/lib/viewjpeg.ps -c \"($Modifiedjpgpath) <</PageSize 2 index viewJPEGgetsize 2 array astore >> setpagedevice viewJPEG\""

set f [open "$command" "r"]
```

After execution i am getting the below error:

```
couldn't open "C:\Program Files(x86)\gs\bin\gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o C:/sample/Et/Alpha_10H00000001.0.00000102.00000001/23.pdf D:/test/1/ghostscript/gs9.19/lib/viewjpeg.ps -c "(\\\\Test-PC\\TRAIL-P\\Ds\\PS\\0\\17\\Color_00000001.jpg) > setpagedevice viewJPEG"": no such file or directory
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­
```

But if i am executing the same command via command prompt it is converting the jpg to pdf file without any error.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your Windows setup is different from the run of the mill, then "`C:\Program Files(x86)`" is incorrect, and should be "`C:\Program Files (x86)`", note the missing space in your definition.

So something like :

```
set command "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\bin\gswin32c.exe........"
```

FWIW Ghostscript doesn't normally install into that directory either, I would expect the directory to be of the form "c:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gsX.YY\bin\gswin32c" where X.YY is the Ghostscript version number.

Comment: That's likely only one of the many problems in the code. OTOH, it's the one that I didn't spot…

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you've got is that you're not running that command as a pipeline.

You need to change:

```
set f [open "$command" "r"]
```

to:

```
set f [open |$command "r"]
```

You may also have typos in your pipeline descriptor, which I recommend you build as a list, and `file nativename` is probably important as well, not so much for the name of the ghostscript interpreter itself, but rather for any filenames that are given to it:

```
# Easiest to use / instead of \ in filenames inside Tcl, really
set gs "C:/Program Files (x86)/gs/bin/gswin32c.exe"
set psscript "D:/test/1/ghostscript/gs9.19/lib/viewjpeg.ps"

# The next bit is building some postscript to run
set thejpgfile [file nativename $Modifiedjpgpath]
set pscmd "($thejpgfile) <</PageSize 2 index viewJPEGgetsize 2 array astore >> setpagedevice viewJPEG"

# Compose everything into a subprocess invokation 
set command [list $gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o $createpdfpath [file nativename $psscript] -c $pscmd]

# Actually run it
set f [open |$command "r"]
```

I find it is usually simpler to try to keep lines of code shorter and use variables to give individual bits a helpful name. It's also a lot easier to debug; you can just print out anything that looks too mysterious.

Comment: Note that this is running it as a pipeline; sometimes, it is easier to do `exec {*}$command` instead.